# Nutch - regex to include only urls which end in a numeric sequence

Tags: regex, web-crawler, nutch

In nutch 1.9, I'm trying to use regex-urlfilter.txt to limit a crawl on the academic research repository at http://eprints.ulster.ac.uk to only return urls for the actual articles, which end in a numeric sequence such as:

http://eprints.ulster.ac.uk/143/
http://eprints.ulster.ac.uk/24122/

and to *exclude* urls such as http://eprints.ulster.ac.uk/view and http://eprints.ulster.ac.uk/cgi/latest/

I have tried various combinations similar to:

-^http://eprints.ulster.ac.uk/[a-z]*/(*)/(*)
+^http://eprints.ulster.ac.uk/[0-9]{1,}/

but nothing seems to work, with the crawl invariably returning no results.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: try: `....([0-9]+(/)?)$`

Comment: Thanks @JorgeCampos what about the line for excluded urls, or should I only worry about the include line?

Comment: Sorry @KoreMike i'm not an expert on nutch I do know regex that's why I give the comment about the line ending with numbers. If you want a line that not end with number I would consider a negative lookahead like `....((?![0-9]+)(/)?)$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct regex for your excludes would be rather something like this:

```
-^http://eprints.ulster.ac.uk(/[a-z]+)+/?
```

- `[a-z]+`: one or more occurences of the letters a-z
- `(...)+`: one or more occurences of the part in the parentheses
- `/?`: optional slash at the end

**Edit:**

I took a look at the site you linked. The structure of it looks like this:

```
1. http://eprints.ulster.ac.uk
    |
    V
2. http://eprints.ulster.ac.uk/view/
    |
    V
3. http://eprints.ulster.ac.uk/view/year/
    |
    V
4. http://eprints.ulster.ac.uk/view/year/2015.html
    |
    V
5. http://eprints.ulster.ac.uk/31307/
```

So 1. is your starting point and 5. is the file you want. If the crawler has to find the last file in the list, it must also fetch the files 2., 3. and 4.

My guess is, that this is exactly your problem. You want to exclude the files 2. and 3., but the crawler needs them. Therefore you can't exclude them from being fetched.

Comment: I tried the following: -^http://eprints.ulster.ac.uk(/[a-z]+)+/?
+^http://eprints.ulster.ac.uk/([0-9]+(/)?)$ but no luck!

Comment: Yes @Sleafar you were right. My understanding of crawling is very limited as yet. I didn't realise that it would need to follow the structure in order to crawl the actual articles